# How to force Google Closure Compiler to rename methods even when using objects

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

It seems that the google closure compiler (http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) preserves all of the method names when I use 'this.' or when using a revealing module pattern. It only seems to rename methods to letters when they are not in an object that might be referenced by other external methods. I've tried wrapping both my (Utility) object and the anonymous method that uses it, but this doesn't seem to help. How do you create objects (and separate script files) that might be shared with each other and still have it abbreviate all the method names?

I'm read several posts on SO and do not see anything addressing this, only posts about stuff not getting renamed due to conflicts with external variables.

```
var Utility = (function () {
    this.isDefined = function (v) {
        /// <summary>Checks to see if a variable is defined.</summary>
        return typeof v !== 'undefined';
    }

this.isObj = function (v) {
    /// <summary>Checks to see if a variable is an object.</summary>
    return typeof v === 'object';
}
...

})();
```

Then I want to be able to do:

```
(function(u) {
    u.isDefined(); 
})(Utility);
```

I've also tried:

```
 var Utility = (function () {
        var utility = {};

        utility.isDefined = function (v) {
            /// <summary>Checks to see if a variable is defined.</summary>
            return typeof v !== 'undefined';
        }

        utility.isObj = function (v) {
            /// <summary>Checks to see if a variable is an object.</summary>
            return typeof v === 'object';
        }

        return utility;
...
```

Comment: Which compiler settings are you using?

Comment: I'm using the basic compiler, although the advanced seems to do the same.

Comment: If the compiler is not renaming properties in advanced mode that means there are extern definitions of the same name or you are using @expose. Enabling type based optimizations helps with the first.

Comment: You do understand that the style of Javascript you have above is very different from the style which is generally intended for use with the Closure Compiler, right?

Answer (score 2):

The revealing object pattern does not work well with closure compiler. Nor does the extra closure you are using which aliases the window and document global variables. The final use case itself is problematic with Closure-compiler as well. Currently, the compiler doesn't handle aliases well especially when passing namespaces as function arguments.

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
var Utility = {};
Utility.isDefined = function (v) {
  /// <summary>Checks to see if a variable is defined.</summary>
  return typeof v !== 'undefined';
};

Utility.isObj = function (v) {
  /// <summary>Checks to see if a variable is an object.</summary>
  return typeof v === 'object';
};

(function() {
   function myPrivateFunction(x) {
   }
   Utility.SomeMethod = function(x) {
     return myPrivateFunction(x);
   };
})();

Utility.isDefined(x);
window['Utility'] = Utility;
```

Compilation and renaming of this example can be tested at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/

You can protect your local variables from bleeding into the global scope by using the `output_wrapper` flag and properly exporting your symbols.

The compiler also specifically disallows usage of the `this` keyword in non-constructor, non-prototype functions. You should always use the full namespace. The compiler can then flatten the namespace methods (which is why the restriction occurs).

See [Which Compilation Level is Right for Me?](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html)

Comment: While passing the window and document in isn't a requirement, using a wrapper around my code isn't the issue. Anything other than a file full of methods doesn't seem to rename. I can put a bunch of methods in an anonymous wrapper and it will rename fine. Also on a side note, who would redo all their code just to support a compiler. The way you do it would not support private methods as they would be in with the rest of the global scope (and doesn't rename anyway). There are several ways I could create the object but none of them seem to rename. This is all good info so thanks.

Comment: Also the example about not using this is not the way I am using it: obj.prop = function() { this.newprop = 'exists' };  >> This is not the same about this.MethodName = >> My this 'is' for prototyping.

Comment: By prototype method, I specifically mean `obj.prototype.method = function() {}`. To use the `this` keyword, the constructor must be invoked with the `new` keyword as well. I added an example of how to have a private function. The important part is the namespace and type information be global.

Comment: Appreciate the reply... but... Why is it important?.. your example doesn't change the method names either, so I don't get the whole point of it. If I want to avoid 'this', I could just define a variable inside my closure and return it. i updated my answer with an example.

Comment: If you could tell me how to define objects, share them, and have their methods rename by the compiler, that is really what I need.

Comment: Renaming like that only occurs using `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` and converting code to be compatible can be daunting. `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` will not rename anything that is exposed to the global scope.

Comment: It's not global.. its wrapped in an anonymous wrapper... and that is why I am posting, because I don't know which advanced optimizations to use.

Comment: Your `return utility;` statement exposes it to the global namespace which is why the compiler won't rename it.

Comment: Right, but i have an anonymous wrapper around that. I was hoping it would be smart enough to detect the scope and rename it everywhere. I guess it's not feasible as it can't detect everywhere I'm passing it and then renaming it where used. I found a workaround by using a different tool and it makes my code very cryptic and beautifying still leaves it the same. Thanks for all the help.